# Invoking assembly that contains web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a DLL that contains web reference and it set to dynamic. That DLL is invoked by another program and the idea is to invoke method from DLL that goes to web service. I use Assembly.LoadFrom method, but when assembly invoked - it is never reads the url from App.Config that located with DLL. How can I make the address be read from App.Config when DLL is invoke dynamically?

Comment: I would kindly suggest to change your title. It is totally irrelevant with your question. Your problem is that you cannot read a value from the app.config...

Comment: Thanks, but I think the subject describes the exact issue. I am not trying to read from App.Config at all. I am trying to work with Web Services. Just need the right way to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

add the app.config where you add the dll and set app.config property copy to output directory = copy always.

Comment: The project on build generates config file. The problem is that it is not read.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the source code of the DLL I would suggest that use error handling.

This would help you a lot in these scenarios. Have the DLL Method check for the app.config file before the method actually runs..

```
public object MyWebServiceDLLMethod()
{
  if(!File.Exists(MyPathToAppConfig))
  {
    throw new Exception("File not found.");
     return null;
  }
  //"real" code for the method goes here. 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you cannot read a value from the app.config. This could be for two reasons:

1. Such a config file does not exist or it is out of scope
2. The config file is actually read, but the specific value you search is not there.

I would check two things. Is an app.config file actually there? If there is an app.config file, does it contain the actual value (url)? 
You should also check if the project referencing  the dll has it's own config file. If it does, this is the config file used from dll to get the respective values.

I would suggest seing [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickmalik/archive/2004/11/25/270420.aspx) post to get a better idea about using config files in .NET.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.